# print out the sequence r1 r2 ... r100 in column

Tags: bash, printf

I would like to have the following output

```
r 1
r 2
r 3
.
.
.
r 100
```

I have tried so far `printf "%s\n" "r {1..100..1}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`r` may be a part of the format:

```
printf 'r %s\n' {1..100}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '%s\n' "r "{1..100..1}""
```

Answer (score -2):

command

```
echo {1..100}| perl -pne "s/ /\n/g"| sed "s/^/r /g"
```

Comment: Changes done KIndly remove down vote

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted.

Comment: Sorry for asking How can i know who downvoted

Comment: i Corrected the code

Comment: Voting is private. Not even us moderators can see who voted on a particular question.

Comment: Ok Thanks@Kusalananda

Comment: @All Let me know the reason for down vote so i can correct it